# Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined when put vue setting in Index.html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i recently learning about `vue`

I have this file `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/lib/buefy.css'
Vue.use(Buefy)

var App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
          message : "It's working"
    }
})
```

and here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vue Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3 id="app">{{ message }}</h3>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>

    <script>

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's working. But, now i'm trying to do something with my script. I change `main.js` (I'm using `webpack`)

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/lib/buefy.css'
Vue.use(Buefy)
```

then my index.html to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vue Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3 id="app">{{ message }}</h3>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>

    <script>
var App = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message:"It's not working"
    }
})
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and i get this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

How can i fix this ?

Comment: I think `var App = new Vue()` should be in `main.js`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to make a new instance of `Vue` directly in `index.html` you should either include the library in your `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
```

Or you need to assign the `Vue` to `window` object in `main.js` like so:

**main.js:**

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
 window.Vue = Vue;
```

then in `index.html` you have access to `Vue()` because it is a global property of `window` object.